# How to load a page in iframe with JavaScript disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I searched the internet about this subject but I didn't find anything about it. Please guide me how is it possible?

For example:

```
<iframe id="iframe1"
        src="Source Link"
        width="890"
        height="640"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: So what you want is to open a page in `iframe` that has Javascript disabled?

Comment: @Eric I want to use iframe on my web page and I want to load this iframe while the Javascript to be disabled for it.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`sandbox`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) attribute.

---

In your particular case use:

```
<iframe id="iframe1"
        src="Source Link"
        width="890"
        height="640"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        allowfullscreen
        sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
```

This re-enables all `iframe` features except for Javascript.

Comment: someone guided me for make deactive advertisements on iframe you can do Javascript disabled for it and now I want to know how is it possible

Comment: If this iframe used Anti Adblock Script what should i do ?

Comment: @Ashkan That script would not run in that `iframe` because Javascript is disabled.

Comment: This Iframe I'm using its a Live Stream that there are some advertisements on it. with javascript disabled we could stop the advertisements but they used Anti Adblock Script till if someone did disabled javascript they can't watch the Live Stream!

Comment: Is there any way ? @eric